# IDBKeyRange querying by key, where key is String

Tags: javascript, client-side, indexeddb, client-side-data

The key of an object stored in IndexedDB is an `Array` of the format:

```
[int, String]
```

e.g. `[1, "Foo"]`, `[9, "Bar"]`

How do I query the database using the string part of the key? For example I want to fetch all records with key `[:any, "Some key"]`.

Looks like [`IDBKeyRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/IDBKeyRange) is used for integer ranges, but I couldn't find a method to build arbitrary queries on keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your index, ensure you set multiEntry to true, ie:

```
objectStore.createIndex("tags","tags", {unique:false,multiEntry:true});
```

You can then get a range using the only operator - assume 'tag' is what you are looking for:

```
var rangeTest = IDBKeyRange.only(tag);
```

And that should do it for you. I've got a full blog entry on this here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/8/10/Searching-for-array-elements-in-IndexedDB

Comment: Much simpler than I thought. Thanks for the quick answer